# How do I return in RestController a list of objects, each object having an image?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple e-learning Rest application, and I ran into a problem of displaying a list of courses.
A course, besides its details, has a cover image that is a MultipartFile (this file is saved on the filesystem and I save the path to it in the database). A course has multiple lectures. A lecture has a video and optional, a list of files associated with it.
Like any main page, you want to display a list of courses, each course having a name, name of the instructor, how many lectures has and a cover image.
My main problem is, how am I supposed to create a CourseDto containing all these details? It is very simple to convert from an entity to a dto by setting the fields of each other, but how do I have to put in a response the cover images for every dto? It is enough to convert that into byte[]?
Or should I create a different endpoint just to download an image using Resource?

Comment: create a different endpoint just to download an image using Resource,
or convert the byte[] into a String encoding it in base64, but what do you have to do with the image?

Comment: As I said, I want to display a list of courses and for every course I want to have a few details and a cover image. Just like you see on Amazon or whatever. I don't really know how to achieve that in case someone comes and want to give a front-end for it :D. Maybe I will go with a different endpoint but I will try that that base64 too.

Comment: For HTML integration you need to provide the URL to the web page to fetch the image, so if that is the goal the specific endpoint is the way.
Base64 strings usually are used to move binary content inside a json.
When you have a separate endpoint, a good thing can be having in the json response a field which has the URI of that endpoint to fetch the image, so that clients can get from there the URI of the image